# What's the difference using only one pthread_t variables and multiple pthread_t variables?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to know differences of using different number of `pthread_t` variables.
Here is a simple code that I made :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *thread(void *vargp);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     pthread_t tid;

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
          *a = i;
          pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, a);
     }

     if(pthread_join(tid, NULL) == -1){
          printf("error");
          exit(1);
     }
}

void *thread(void *vargp)
{
     int count = 1;
     for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
          printf("count : %d, value : %d\n", count, (*(int *)vargp));
          count++;
     }
}
```

It works well as I mean to. However, what I thought strange is that it create 5 threads but using only one pthread_t variable !.. I saw some examples where using same number of pthread variables with number of thread it will create. For example, If I gonna create 5 threads like below, I have to create 5 length `pthread_t` array, like `pthread_t tid[5]` . Could you tell me what's differences? Thanks

Comment: In your example, you'll only join on the last thread that you created.  There's nothing that says that the other thread will complete first.  If you need to keep track of all your threads, then you need to keep track of all the `pthread_t` values returned by `pthread_create()` (until you don't need them anymore or pass the responsibility to something else).  It's similar in concept to keeping track of memory allocations - until you free the memory (or pass the ownership of the memory to something else), you need to keep the pointer around to be able to use and free the memory block.

Answer (score 4):

`pthread_t` variable passed to `pthread_create` is a thread identifier and it can be reused as you please. So there's nothing wrong with the way you used the same idenitfier `tid` to create multiple threads. But you'll lose the identity of all other threads except the last one created using it as `tid` is continuously overwritten in the loop.

However, if you would like to receive an exit value from the thread (using `pthread_join`) or like to do some other operations such as detaching it (using `pthread_detach` -- you could create a thread in detached state or the thread itself can detach it), set/get scheduling parameters (using `pthread_setschedparam`, `pthread_getschedparam`) etc, from the main thread you can't do that since you don't have the thread's ID.

In short, the code is perfectly fine and you'll need to store the IDs (such as using an array `tid[5]` in your example) if you want to manipulate the threads from *outside* (as opposed to from within the thread -- a thread can get its ID using `pthread_self()`).

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume you want to create 5 threads then execute some code at the main thread and then wait for all the other threads to end before returning from the main thread.
In this case you will have to keep the pthread_t's for the future usage at pthread_join.